# Fluent NHibernate One-to-One mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-one

I am having a really hard time exploiting HasOne mapping with Fluent NHibernate. Basically, the class A can have a matching (only one or none) record in the class B.

Please help with the AMap and BMap classes that define the relationships.

Thank you.

```
public class A
{
   public virtual int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual string P1 {get;set;}
   public virtual string P2 {get;set;}
   public virtual string P3 {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
   public virtual int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual string P4 {get;set;}
   public virtual string P5 {get;set;}
   public virtual string P6 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't `Employee` inherit from `Person`? As an `Employee` is a type of `Person`. Then you can use NHibernate's inheritance facilities when mapping these classes.

Comment: Hi penfold. You are probably right but I asked my question the wrong way I guess. Here is what I am really trying to do. Table A has properties Id,p1,p2,p3. Table B has properties Id,p4,p5,p6. Every record in Table A can have maximum of one matching record in Table B buut it also can have none. It's basically One-to-one relationships (zero or one to be exact).

Comment: Do you have any tables for other roles? If so how do you identify that a person is an Employee and not, for example, a Contractor? Is this done by the existence of records in a table, such as the Employee table? Or is there a column in the Person table that identifies the role of the person? Please can you update your question with this information.

Comment: I did edit my question penfold. You don't have to look at it like Person-Employee relationship anymore. It just a table A (main table) and table B which can be looked like an extension of table A. It is a one-to-one record relationship. Sorry for messing my initial example.

Comment: Sorry didn't see the updated question before I posted.

Answer (score 8):

To get `one-to-one` mapping working you will need to add a property of type `B` to class `A` and vice versa as per the code below.  These references are required in both classes since NHibernate doesn't support unidirectional one-to-one.

```
public class A
{
  public virtual int Id {get;set;}
  public virtual string P1 {get;set;}
  public virtual string P2 {get;set;}
  public virtual string P3 {get;set;}
  public virtual B child { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
  public virtual int Id {get;set;}
  public virtual string P4 {get;set;}
  public virtual string P5 {get;set;}
  public virtual string P6 {get;set;}
  public virtual A parent;
}
```

Then in the fluent mappings you will need to add the following

```
public AMap()
{
  /* mapping for id and properties here */
  HasOne(x => x.child)
      .Cascade.All();
}

public BMap()
{
  /* mapping for id and properties here */
  References(x => x.parent)
      .Unique();
}
```

Please note that the one-to-many mapping in `BMap` is marked as `Unique`. This is used to create a unique column constraint if you use NHibernate to generate the DB schema.

To create a new record you would then write something like:

```
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var classA = new A();
        classA.child = new B() { parent = classA};

        session.Save(owner);
        transaction.Commit();
    }
```

Finally one caveat, the current release of NHibernate, 3.4, doesn't support cascade deletes of orphaned one-to-ones. See [here](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1262) for the bug report. This means if you write something like `session.Delete(classA);` then the associated class B record won't be automatically deleted.