# Fluent NHibernate one-to-one mapping not working (again.....)

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-one

The more messages I read about it the more I get confused! Maybe I simply understand something wrong... I have two entities: Computer and OperatingSystem, both have a few dozens properties.
The relation I like to map is `one-to-one`, one computer has one OS. To shorten I only show relevant properties:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string CUser { get; set; }

    protected EntityBase()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        CDate = DateTime.Now;
        var wi = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        if (wi != null)
            CUser = wi.Name;
    }
}


public class ComputerDb : EntityBase
{
    public virtual string ComputerType { get; set; }
    public virtual string Domain { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    /* ...... */
    public virtual OsDb Os { get; set; }

    public virtual void AddOs(OsDb os)
    {
        this.Os = os;
    }

public class ComputerDbMap : ClassMap<ComputerDb>
{
    public ComputerDbMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(x => x.ComputerType).Nullable().Length(16);
        Map(x => x.Domain).Nullable().Length(64);
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable().Length(64);
        /* .... */
        HasOne(x => x.Os).Cascade.All().PropertyRef(x => x.Computer);
    }
}

public class OsDb : EntityBase
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual bool? PartOfCluster { get; set; }
    /* ... */
    public virtual ComputerDb Computer { get; set; } 
}

public class OsDbMap : ClassMap<OsDb>
{
    public OsDbMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(x => x.Name).Nullable().Length(128).Index("Idx_OsName");
        Map(x => x.Description).Nullable().Length(128);
        Map(x => x.PartOfCluster).Nullable();
        /* .... */
        References(x => x.Computer, "Computer_Id").Unique();
    }
}
```

In the program I do:

```
var computer = getComputerDb(ps);
var os = getOsDb(ps);
computer.AddOs(os);
var o = new Operations();
o.AddComputerToDb(computer);
```

where

```
public void AddComputerToDb(ComputerDb cpDb)
{
    using (var session = _sessionManager.OpenSession())
    {
       using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
       {
           try
           {
               session.SaveOrUpdate(cpDb);
               transaction.Commit();
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Log.Error($"Exception in AddComputerToDb(). Exception: {e}");
               transaction.Rollback();
               throw;
           }
           finally
           {
               session.Close();
           }
     }
}
```

Here the result of the select on the tblComputerDb table on SQLServer:
[image: Data from the ComputerDb entity]
And here the result from the tblOsDb table:
[image: Data from the OsDb entity]

**Problem:** *Computer_Id is NULL*. If I understand things right, it should contain the GUID of the computer record `053DFFDF-0A88-4270-8405-A5EE00FFD388`. I do not understand, why it cannot fill this Id from the computer entity. Modelling as ONE-TO-MANY works just fine, but is NOT what I want...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's the addOs method doing? computer.AddOs(os); is it directly assigning the child, like this example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724562/fluent-nhibernate-one-to-one-mapping

Comment: Yes, similar to adding an object to a collection if it would be one-to-many.